Trying to build a python API, but getting this error for Quart library as not found

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'quart'> File Path "C:\xxxxxS\xx\xxxl\NewProjects\xxxx\my_api_env\app.py", line 3, in 
from quart import Quart, request, jsonify, send_file, BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quart'

This above error is occuring when I run the app.py on VS code.
Also tried running it from CMD,
but here another error is occuring as mentioned below-

File "C:\xxxxxS\xx\xxxl\NewProjects\xxxx\my_api_env\app.py", line 8, in 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Not sure what is that I'm missing here?
When I list for file/folder - it shows Quart with version 0.19. already in the dependency list.
Tried to build an Python API using Flask,
Was expecting that the API will perform/ run without any errors.
But it threw above mentioned errors.
so unable to proceed further.

How do you run your code? How do you install and list your dependencies? If you see bs4 and quart in your dependencies, most likely you're running your code with a different python environment.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you install all the modules (quart and bs4)?
pip install quart
pip install beautifulsoup4

Then check if you see these two modules in the list with the following commands and try to un your application.
pip list

If it's still not working try to reinstall the modules.
Make sure to do all these things after you have activated your virtual environment, the one where the dependencies are installed.
